# How to order queryset while keeping objects grouped by other field?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have a model with two fields date and type:

```
class Obj(Model):
    date = DateTimeField
    type = ChoiceField
```

I want to order them by their creation date but I want the same type objects to stick together
OBJECT:

- 01.01.2022 BLUE
- 02.01.2022 BLACK
- 03.01.2022 BLUE
- 04.01.2022 GREEN
- 05.01.2022 BLUE
- 06.01.2022 BLACK
- 07.01.2022 GREEN

When I order I want it to look at the date first, get the latest date, then take all the objects with that object's type and put them into order keeping the date order amongst them, and then it will take the second type's next date and put them into the order after the previous one:

ORDERED:

- 07.01.2022 GREEN
- 04.01.2022 GREEN
- 06.01.2022 BLACK
- 02.01.2022 BLACK
- 05.01.2022 BLUE
- 03.01.2022 BLUE
- 01.01.2022 BLUE

So what I want is basically order_by title first, and then order the groups by date
Can I do this trivially or do I have to go Case When or maybe even raw SQL
It would be best if I can avoid raw SQL because this is paginated

The naive approach `order_by("type", "date")` would result in something *similar* to my desired result but it is not ordered by the date in the queryset but ordered by type first so it would have the type's order as the main ordering. Resulting in:

- 06.01.2022 BLACK
- 02.01.2022 BLACK
- 05.01.2022 BLUE
- 03.01.2022 BLUE
- 01.01.2022 BLUE
- 07.01.2022 GREEN
- 04.01.2022 GREEN

Comment: Is this something that `order_by()` doesn't work with? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: There are four ways you can use order_by with 2 fields. `order_by("date")`, `order_by("type")`, `order_by("title", "date")`, `order_by("date", title)`. None of them returns the above result because it applies both of the orderings at the same time without not caring about the grouping I want to achieve.

Comment: I would expect `order_by("type", "date")` to work - you put "title" in your comment, is that just a typo or have you put the wrong field in?

Comment: Typo, fixed it. And edited the question with your example and why doesn't it work.

Comment: It almost looks right but the types are the wrong way around (A-Z not Z-A), does `order_by("-type", "date")` get you there?

Comment: We don't want Z-A, we want them to be ordered by the last item's date. green black blue, that's why I gave the example result with those colors, so you know we don't want the end result to be ordered alphabetically but by the last item's date first

Comment: Last added item is a green type of object, so we get all the greens to the top and order them amongst all the green ones and put them at top, after all the greens are done the next object created latest is a black object, we get all the blacks, order them amongst blacks and put them after greens, after all the green and blacks are done the next is blue, we order them and append.

Comment: I'm with you - the Z-A is just a coincidence, but you want types to be grouped together but ordered by the date the type was first created. Not sure if you can do that with order_by, you might need to do it pythonically - I will have a think

Comment: Doing it in python defeats the whole purpose because I'd have to get all the items from the db, I can get away with SQL __at worst__ because at least then I can paginate without worrying about fetching all objects from the db unlike doing it in python

Comment: You could annotate a subquery which gets the latest time of the current `type` and then order by this annotated value and the `date` field. I don't know how efficient this query would be though.

Comment: Hmmm, something like that might work, but also might result in the same caveat we have here with order_by(type, date) at the end. I'll give it a shot and let y'all know here. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I just understand what you mean and yeah that feels like an inefficient query, but at least it solves the problem. And since this query won't have more than 5 figure objects I assume I may get away with this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I think I have an answer for you that works - you would need to use Subquery and OuterRef. The first queryset orders all of the Obj models by the date that you want but filtered with OuterRef - the OuterRef gets the type field from the second line.

The second line then does the annotation with a subquery of the first line, the `.values('date')[:1]` gets the last date value (which you may want to change around). The annotation means that each object is labelled with the date that the newest object with that type was created on.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

dates = Obj.objects.filter(type=OuterRef('type')).order_by('-date')
Obj.objects.annotate(
    newest_creation=Subquery(dates.values('date')[:1])
).order_by('date', 'newest_creation')
```

You might need to change the ordering of the date and newest_creation to get your desired ordering.

Comment: Yep I've did something similar so I'm assuming this works also